# How can I call assembly custom function from custom code editor in SSRS2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, .net-assembly, custom-code

I look around and I found a lot of answers about making assembly code and call a function of the assembly from Report control through expression. but I need to know how to call a function of th assembly custom code from custom code editor. I have success to call a function from report expression in text control but when I try to call the same function from inside of custom code editor the BIDS preview send a error of declaration instance error. Example After make the reference in a text box expression write Code.Limits.GetMe("LegendLimit1") works but when in custom code I try

```
Dim test as string
Test = Limits.Get("LegendLimit1")
'Or
Test = SSRS.Library.Limits.Get("LegendLimit1")
```

Has the error

Comment: This article describes everything you need I think. It also contains a lot of things that you have already done but it is complete.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920769/how-to-use-custom-assemblies-or-embedded-code-in-reporting-services

Comment: Thanks for your answer, probably I need to clarify when I talked about custom code in editor I am talking about embedded code in Report then is how can I call an assembly custom code function from embedded code in Report